# bokeh interactor and push_notebook doesn't refresh in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plot, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I found [a way](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.4.3/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb) to implement interactive slider using Bokeh without relying on Bokeh server, since Bokeh server [doesn't work in VS code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10765#issuecomment-739543791).

But this new way doesn't work in vs code either, though it still works in web browser.

Is it possible to run it in vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jupyter mentioned in your link is used, so please install the jupyter extension and create the `.ipynb` file.

[image]

I used the **basic interactor demo** in the [link](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.4.3/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb).

[image]

After all execution, I can get the content shown in the figure:

[image]

Of course, when you adjust the scroll bar below, you need to rerun the penultimate cell:

[image]

Comment: Smart idea. Any way to skip the step 2 though? It's of great value to see continuous change on graph when move the slider, so I know what those variables mean.

Comment: @David H. J. This is not supported at present. It can only be refreshed manually. You can request a new feature in GitHub [jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter) or [bokeh](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh).

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT are the Bokeh Jupyter extensions installed? `push_notebook` is implemented using notebook comms, which require an extension (nothing we can do about that)

Comment: @bigreddot This can't be searched in the extension store. Could you please paste a link for me to check it?

Comment: That's because it is a Jupyter extension, not a VSCode extension: https://github.com/bokeh/jupyter_bokeh#jupyter_bokeh I can't guarantee this extensions makes things work in "JupyterLab inside VSCode" btw, the extension is only tested with plain JupyterLab.

Comment: @bigreddot I've just tried it. It seems that it doesn't work in the jupyter notebook of vscode